# Concat and stream multiple mkv files from a DVR

Tags: php, streaming, apache

Have surveillance data organized as short video files having variable duration:

```
./20150914/cam2-23-24-10.mkv
./20150914/cam2-23-32-40.mkv
./20150914/cam2-23-43-04.mkv
./20150914/cam2-23-54-17.mkv
./20150915/cam2-00-02-54.mkv
./20150915/cam2-00-03-16.mkv
./20150915/cam2-00-04-22.mkv
./20150915/cam2-00-54-10.mkv
```

Need a module for apache that takes URL like: `http://localhost/cam2/20150914/23-25-00.webm`, finds the best matching first file `cam2-23-24-10.mkv`, seeks 50 seconds, and outputs a webm stream. On EOF it should continue streaming, taking the data from subsequent files.

I can reorganize the directory structure, use mp4 instead of mkv, if needed, but I can't make video segments have static length.

What options do I have?
As far as I know, `ffserver` can't stream local files, so I need apache. I could make a cgi script with command line `ffmpeg`, but maybe there's already a php solution?